# Make yComb plot start at zero

Tags: pgfplots

I currently use this code to create a plot:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[ycomb,mark=*] coordinates  {(0, 13) (1, 12) (2, 11) (3, 13) (4, 13) (5, 13) (6, 12) (7, 12) (8, 12) (9, 14)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

While this kind of representation is great for showing the difference between the individual data points, this is entirely irrelevant for what I want to show. The point of this plot is to show that the data points are close together. I want the y axis to start at zero. How can this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `ymin = 0` as an option to the `axis`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ymin=0]
    \addplot[ycomb,mark=*] coordinates  {(0, 13) (1, 12) (2, 11) (3, 13) (4, 13) (5, 13) (6, 12) (7, 12) (8, 12) (9, 14)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]